# Let $P$ have a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, and, conditional on $P=p$, let $X$ have a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $P$ have a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, and, conditional on $P=p$, let $X$ have a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$. Find the conditional distribution of $P$ given $X$.

Comment: You should tell us your attempts.   Perhaps your textbook has a similar problem just before this...

Comment: Hint: Bayesian posterior inference using Beta-Binomial Model.